# How can you check if object is moving/not moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make a simple script that when u clicked the screen the ball in the game will move (20000 * Time.deltaTime) to the right, and then if i'll click again, it will move to the left side and then right and so on.

I managed to get the ball to move to the right, but i need it to wait after the animation is finish because i need to check if the player clicked again (if he did i need to check to what direction to move the ball).
I tried many methods i found online like checking if Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude == 0.0f that means the ball is not moving..

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public Transform PlayerPosition;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.AddForce(20000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); // moving ball to the right
        while (rb.velocity.magnitude != 0.0f) // I tried to check until the ball is not moving 
        {

        }
        Debug.Log(PlayerPosition.position.x);
    }
}
```

**And here is my latest try:**

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.AddForce(20000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); // moving ball to the right
        if(rb.velocity.magnitude < 0.05f) // if i click the ball it just prints it and not wating for the ball to not move
        {
            Debug.Log(PlayerPosition.position.x);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output to wait until the animation is finished but instead, its printing the vaule(x) the moment i click the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
rb.velocity.magnitude != 0.0f
```

will almost **allways** be `true` due to [single precision floatong point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) : Two float values even if they seem to be equal logical are most likely not.

So you can either use a threshold how you tried already

```
if(rb.velocity.magnitude <= 0.5f)
```

or use [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) which uses a very small [Epsilon](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) or threshold for the comparing

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.magintude, 0))
```

---

Than it sounds like you want to wait until the ball has stopped moving and than output the position - like e.g. for a billard game. So actually there seems to be no [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) involved.

In most cases where you think/speek of of an "animation" you actually mean "doing something over time" not to confuse with using an `Animator` or `Animation` component with `AnimationClip`s in Unity.

You can/should use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public Transform PlayerPosition;

// a flag to make sure there is only one animation at a time
private bool isMoving;

// a flag for altering between left and right movement
private bool isMovingRight;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // only allow clicks while not moving already
    if (!isMoving && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // stop further input until not moving anymore
        isMoving = true;

        // add the force 
        // (you might btw want to skip that Time.deltaTime here it makes no sense)
        rb.AddForce(isMovingRight ? 20000 : -20000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        // alter the direction for the next call
        isMovingRight = !isMovingRight;

        // if you rather want to be able to interrupt the current animation by clicking again
        // remove the isMoving flag and instead use this
        //StopCoroutine(WaitForMoveStops());  

        // Start the routine
        StartCoroutine(WaitForMoveStops());
    }
}

private IEnumerator WaitForMoveStops()
{
    // Inside a Coroutine while is okey now
    // as long as you yield somwhere

    // check if velocity is below threshold
    while (!Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.magnitude, 0) 
    {
        // yield in simple words means "leave" this method here, render the frame
        // and than continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // I would now hard reset the velocity just to be sure
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;

    Debug.Log(PlayerPosition.position.x);

    // whatever you want to do now

    // reset the flag to allow input again
    isMoving = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

You need to check if your animation is still playing. You are checking only if your velocity is greater than 0.05f, which is correctly printing out the statement.

Use [`Animation.IsPlaying(string name)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.IsPlaying.html). One caveat is that this method will return `false` for the same frame of `Update` that it was invoked, since the animation hasn't technically started until afterward.

```
void Update()
{
    if (!rb.velocity.magnitude <= 0.01f && !Animation.IsPlaying(nameOfAnimation))
    {
        Debug.Log("We're not moving and the animation is not playing");
    }
}
```

---

### Original

You should not need to use `while` in your `Update` method.

Use an `if` statement inside of your `Update`

```
void Update()
{
    if (rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.01f) Debug.Log("We're moving!");
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3'

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `rb.velocity.magnitude` instead to get the float

Comment: so in order to check if it is not moving u do if (rb.velocity.magnitude != 0)?

Comment: "Magnitude" by virtue is an absolute number. I would just check if it's `> 0` rather than `!= 0`, because `float` will almost never be 0. They end up being something like 0.000001

Comment: You can also use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) to determine your float equality

Comment: you can simply check if the magnitude is smaller than a small value for example `0.05` like this `rb.velocity.magnitude <  0.05f`

Comment: Albeit, the question does state "How can you check if object is moving?", so let's go with `rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.05f`

Comment: @MiladQasemi I updated the post with my latest try please review it, i still get the same result..

Comment: could you provide example using WatingForAnimaiton? because it is getting a string

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to move it if it's stopped, then call AddForce only when it's idle:

```
var wasMovingLastTime = false;    

void Update()
{
    var isMoving = rb.velocity.magnitude > 0f;

    if (wasMovingLastTime && !isMoving)
    {
        /// Has just finished moving
        Debug.Log(PlayerPosition.position.x);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (!isMoving)
        {
            rb.AddForce(20000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    wasMovingLastTime = isMoving;
}
```

Comment: thanks that solved one problem for me, but if I want to print the x value after the animation is finished?

Comment: @yarinCohen You'll have to use a flag. Check out the update